# Insides of glass is white

Tags: shaders, lighting, glass, reflection

The reflections in some areas of my glass material is white. The environment is a dark room with a few point lights. There are no bright light sources or objects in the scene that would make such a reflection. [image]

The problem appears to be coming from the point lights in the scene. The white reflections are the radius of the points lights, but the reflections in the glass are not an accurate reflection of the actual lights. Only in the reflection of the glass, the radius of the point lights show up as solid white objects.

Comment: Is the glass object completely solid or have you given it thickness with the solidify modifier?

Comment: I used the solidify modifier.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the *Object Properties* for the light and disable (un-check) *Transmission* under *Ray Visibility*:

[image: Trans1]

[image: Trans2]

Comment: That did it. Thanks!